# how do i make two new lists based on what the index is in a list?

Tags: python

So I think it is much easier to explain if I show an example:

```
things = ["black", 7, "red', 10, "white", 15]
```

two new lists based on whether the index was even or odd.

```
color = ["black", "red","white"]
size = [7,10,15]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [4]: things = ["black", 7, "red", 10, "white", 15]

In [5]: color = things[::2]

In [6]: color
Out[6]: ['black', 'red', 'white']

In [7]: size = things[1::2]

In [8]: size
Out[8]: [7, 10, 15]
```

Comment: how come it does not work on this instance? any idea?                     color = [u'Black,\xa06', u'Black,\xa06.5', '']

Comment: colors = color[::2] print colors
[u'Black,\xa06', '']

Comment: @slopeofhope: because they do not alternate in the list.

Comment: what do you mean? and do you have a solution for that?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
things = ["black", 7, "red", 10, "white", 15]
two_lists = zip(*[(x,things[things.index(x)+1]) for x in things[::2]])

>>> two_lists[0]
('black', 'red', 'white')
>>> two_lists[1]
(7, 10, 15)
```

the list manip part `[(x,things[things.index(x)+1]) for x in things[::2]]` seperates it into 3 list pairs ( almost like its ready for a dictionary or something... so cray cray)

the `zip(*` part, turns the whole array on its side

if you just did `[(x,things[things.index(x)+1]) for x in things[::2]]` withotu the zip part, then you could call `dict()` on it and return a dictionary, which might be more useful

```
>>> a = [(x,things[things.index(x)+1]) for x in things[::2]]
>>> a
[('black', 7), ('red', 10), ('white', 15)]
>>> cool_dict = dict(a)
>>> cool_dict['black']
7
```